# How adding timestamp to primary key can help in returning faster search results?

Tags: sql, database, nosql, system-design, low-latency

I was studying one of articles where it was mentioned that services like twitter shard their data based on tweet ids. Also to improve latency, they add timestamp to their tweet ids. Like tweet id could be of 64 bits , first 40 bits can store current epoch seconds and remaining part could be an auto incrementing number. How does it improve timeline feed generation of a user ? How does adding timestamp to id improve read performance ?

Comment: A citation from the articles that shows the statement and its context might help...

Answer (score 1):

Because it is, by default, showing the first 'x' records ordered by timestamp

or

Because it is, by default, showing the records created in the last 24 hours (or any other time period you want) - ordered by timestamp

Comment: Suppose earlier there was an auto incrementing number as ID, wouldn't that only be enough to judge the freshness of entry. I mean to say , the higher the ID , the newer is the post. Why to add timestamp to it ?